# iPad app using Xcode, how to take user text input and display it in another text field

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, text, ascii

I am rather new to iOS coding and am trying to make an application where when the user types in some text the app output their text in ASCII art.

I just want to know how I can get the app to realise when the user types "The" that it has to realise that there is a `T` a `H` and an `E` and put out a certain list of characters.

I am making this for the iPad, using a "Tabbed application" pre-made workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your viewcontroller is the delegate of the "entry" text field. Implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and make the equivalent changes to the string of your "art" text field. Make sure you return YES at the end so that the entry text field can actually be updated.